# Drawing text at different heights in CesiumJS

Tags: cesiumjs

I'm trying to draw some text at a particular height (so it's drawn at the same height as some other primitive) in Cesium. Text-wise, I can't seem to be able to draw anything but labels clamps to the ground (in the example below, the first little circle is at ground level). As such:

```js
var entity = viewer.entities.add({
            position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(parseFloat(terrain[5]), parseFloat(terrain[4])),
            ellipse : {
              semiMinorAxis : 10000,
              semiMajorAxis : 10000,
              height : 1000,
              fill : true,           
              outline: true,
              material : Cesium.Color.fromCssColorString(someColour).withAlpha(0.5),
              outlineWidth : 2
            },
            label: {
                id: 'my label',
                text: "Blabla",
                scale: .5,
                height: 1000
              }
         });
```

[image]

Is there any way to draw text at a specific height in Cesium?

Comment: The text height needs to be part of `entity.position`.  Try adding it as a 3rd parameter to `Cartesian3.fromDegrees` on the 2nd line there.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly!!! would you like to turn it into an answer?

Comment: Sure, glad it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text height needs to be part of `entity.position`. Try adding it as a 3rd parameter to `Cartesian3.fromDegrees` on the 2nd line there.